# Использование метода родительского класса в дочернем классе Python

Tags: python, ооп, классы, методы, return

Предположим есть два класса: Triangle вычисляет площадь равнобедренного треугольника и Pyramid, который, пользуясь возвратом вычисления, вычисляет площадь пирамиды.

```
import math


class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, a, h):
        self.figure_name = "Треугольник"
        self.a = a
        self.h = h

    @property
    def square(self):
        return 0.5 * self.a * self.h


class Pyramid(Triangle):
    def __init__(self, a, h):
        super().__init__(a, h)
        self.figure_name = 'Пирамида'

    @property
    def square(self):
        side_square = 4 * super().square
        base_square = self.a ** 2
        return side_square + base_square


p = Pyramid(6, 4)
print(p.square)
```

Название метода одинаковое в обоих классах.
Как все-таки получить результат вычисления Triangle.square в методе square класса Pyramid, пользуясь наследованием, а не таким некрасивым способом? Может какой-то декоратор поможет ?

Comment: в возврате вместо `side_square + Triangle(self.a, self.h).square` прописать `return side_square + super().square` - через `super` мы можем обратиться к базовому классу

Comment: А откуда вообще такое странное желание отнаследовать пирамиду от треугольника? Разве можно про пирамиду сказать, что она является треугольником?

Comment: И что такое h применительно к треугольнику?

Comment: @Xander Боковые грани правильной треугольной пирамиды, по сути, является равнобедренными треугольниками (формула, похоже, неправильная). Поэтому зная площадь одной боковой грани, ты знаешь площадь трёх боковых граней, а там уже дело за малым. h - высота треугольника и апофема пирамиды. Понимаю, что легче было сразу посчитать, но тогда бы вопроса не было)

Comment: Суть в том, что здесь наследование не применимо, т.к. пирамида состоит из треугольников, но при этом не является треугольником.

Comment: @Xander Смотри. Формула площади пирамиды: S_пирамиды_ = 4 * S_бок_ + S_основ_, где S_бок_ - площадь боковой грани (их 4), которая представляет из себя треугольник и S_основ_- площадь основания, которая представляет из себя квадрат. Я сейчас изменю код в вопросе на исправленный. Может станет понятнее, почему хотел с обращением к треугольнику

Comment: @Daniil Loban Спасибо) А как отметить, что ответ был полезен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `super()` используется для предоставления доступа к методам и свойствам родительского класса. Она возвращает объект, представляющий экземпляр родительского класса, который был ранее инициирован в конструкторе дочернего класса.

Таким образом, свойство родительского класса `square` можно прочитать
таким образом :

```
super().square
```

Что касается ООП и двух классов Треугольник и Пирамида, то я бы выбрал ассоциацию.

> **Ассоциация** – это когда один класс включает в себя другой класс в
> качестве одного из полей.

Таким образом в конструкторе Пирамиды можно завести свойство, которое будет использоваться для вычисления площади, если площадь не будет изменятся, если она будет изменятся то не забывать обновлять и это поле.

Наследование используют в тех случаях когда хотят расширить класс новыми методами и свойствами или переопределить некоторые методы. Т.е. в данном случае связь между Треугольником и Пирамидой действительно плохо прослеживается. Классическим примером тут будут классы Круг, Треугольник, Квадрат базовым классом для которых будет Фигура

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно уже отметили в комментариях, пирамида не является треугольником. Следовательно класс пирамиды неправильно наследовать от треугольника.

То что вы хотите использовать готовый функционал вычисления площади треугольника - это правильно, вот только неправильно для этого использовать наследование.

Правильно будет испольльзовать класс Triangle без наследования:

```
class Pyramid:
    def __init__(self, a, h):
        self.a = a
        self.h = h
        self.figure_name = "Пирамида"

    @property
    def square(self):
        side_square = 4 * Triangle(self.a, self.h).square
        base_square = self.a ** 2
        return side_square + base_square
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо) Почитаю в каких случаях стоит и не стоит использовать наследование. Просто в данном примере мне было интересно как использовать результат метода родительского класса в методе с таким же названием в дочернем классе.